# "Toggle" an element without using JS, AND without using input[type=checkbox]+*

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used to just use Javascript to toggle elements, which was annoying.

Then I learned of doing it this way, which seemed like a godsend:

```
<script type="text/css">
input[type=checkbox]+div
{
display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked+div
{
display:block;
}
</script>

<label for="foo"><button>Toggle!</button></label>
<input id="foo" type="checkbox" />
<div>
This is getting toggled.
</div>
```

That works, but it's very much a hack that doesn't make any sense semantically, unless you're actually styling stuff in a form.

Someone pointed out the `:target` selector the other day, which is easier and makes much more sense semantically:

```
<script type="text/css">
a
{
display:none;
}
a:target
{
display:block;
}
</script>

<a href="#foo"><button>Toggle!</button></a>
<a id="foo">
This is getting toggled.
</a>
```

The trade-off is that, unlike a checkbox, the target is one-way: a checkbox goes on and off, whereas a target just goes "on". To make it go "off" you have to click another anchor, which isn't always desirable.

Is there some kind of way of toggling in a semantically-appropriate way without having to resort to Javascript?

Comment: No. Dynamically changing the document in response to user interaction is what JavaScript was designed for.

Comment: CSS-tricks for form interaction can be pretty cool if your needs are low. But even I've had to do things like completely re-implement the `label for=""` feature for more specific needs. I would say if the JavaScript was annoying you, you might consider somehow "defining" your toggle elements entirely in HTML, for instance setting up `data-` attributes to specify toggling options. Then, query your whole HTML for relevant elements and you won't have to add more JavaScript for each one.